# Database partitioning on SQL server 2014 Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

Can we do database partitioning (not table/view partition) on SQL server 2014 Standard Edition?

By doing database partitioning, I want to place files on different physical drives.

If not possible, please share link from site like Microsoft etc. mentioning that Standard Edition is not supported.

Comment: Placing files on different drives is **not** partitioning (at least not what's commonly understood by that in a RDBMS). Partitioning means that one (large) table is physically split into several smaller ones based on a value in one of the table's columns.

Comment: Good place to start is with the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For all I know, in SQL Server you can put one or more tables in a filegroup, but you cannot break one table into multiple filegroups unless you are using partitioning. Since Standard Edition does not allow partitioning, it seems you are out of luck.

Now, I may regret saying this, but...

What you could consider is to mimic partitioning by splitting your stuff into two or more tables e.g. TABLE1, TABLE2, and so on. Then you place each table on a different filegroup. You can even create a view that does UNION ALL with the tables, so your SELECT queries can hit just one thing, though for INSERT or UPDATE you will probably need to go back to the tables.

Of course, this is NOT PARTITIONING, and you lose a lot of the benefits, from partition operations (switch, split, merge) to engine optimisation, to index management and surely other aspects.
In other words, **I would not do this unless I know exactly what I'm doing**.